# Copy row from one DataGridGiew to another DataGridGiew where row fore-color is red in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, background-color, rows

Can anybody give the example how to copy the row from one Datagridview to another DataGridView where row is fore-color is red.

I saw in web they are related selected rows copying. But I have to copy only where row is fore-color is red.

This code I am using :

```
               int k = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dgdPrview.Columns)
            {
                dgdMissingAcc.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dgdPrview.Rows)
            {
     if (dgdPrview.Rows[k][0].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor == System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                {                        
                  dgdMissingAcc.Rows.Add(dgvRow); //Error:Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control.
                    k++;

                }
            }
          dgdMissingAcc.Show();
```

// updated second foreach loop:

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dgdPrview.Rows)
            {
                var cellcount = dgdPrview.ColumnCount; //here I take the column count not the row count.
                if (dgdPrview.Rows[k][0].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor == System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < cellcount; i++)
                    {
                       dgdMissingAcc.Rows[k][0].Cells[i].Value = dgdPrview.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();

                    }
                }
                k++;
            }
```

When I come to the third row am getting index out of range exception. Let me know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Try out and let me know what happens regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Try to put condition roughly like

```
if(gridview.CellStyle.ForeColor == Color.Red)
{
}
```

this can vary according to cellstyle or rowstyle...

Plz refer the link so that you can get more idea regarding the things>>>

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/320268/datagridview-color-change-based-on-condition

```
int k = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dgdPrview.Columns)
            {
                dgdMissingAcc.Columns.Add(c.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
            }

            for(int i=0;i<dgdPrview.rows.count;i++)
            {
     if (dgdPrview.Rows[k].Cells[i].Style.ForeColor == System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                {                        
                  dgdMissingAcc.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value=dgdPrview.CurrentRow.Cells[i].value.toString();
                }
            }
          dgdMissingAcc.Show();
```

Comment: can you tell me where I am doing mistake.

Comment: put for loop for last if...condition check will be.>>>dgdPrview.Rows[k].Cells[i].Style.ForeColor == System.Drawing.Color.Red

Comment: copy the grid something like this>>>dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();

Comment: I am getting Error :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index. Can you see my second foreach loop

Comment: this error is comming bcoz we r doing something mistake in accessing for loop variables(i)...i dont now why u r taking column count???

Comment: i have made some editions in your answer...by mistake one index is kept blank...eg dgdMissingAcc.Rows[i][0]....set it in appropriate positions...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want like this:

```
    private DataGridView CopyWhereForeColorIsRed(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dgv2 = new DataGridView();
        dgv2.Rows.AddRange(dgv.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(a=>a.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Any(c=>c.Style.ForeColor == Color.Red))
            .ToArray());

        return dgv2;
    }
```